# Getting Twig_Error_Runtime when trying to open the website

Tags: templating, php

I am trying to set up a Craft CMS website with Twig. I have done all the setup but getting the following error when I try to open the website-

```html
Twig_Error_Runtime

Variable "global" does not exist in "503" at line 9 (C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php:436)

#0 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\storage\runtime\compiled_templates\00\0009102817a5d89769207212bd179d422974c0400e0d4db894ad4fd45f35fd9d.php(29): Twig_Template->getContext(Array, 'global')
#1 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php(381): __TwigTemplate_37e5d62204d15e3586ae79a226d2d0e58f18084c697fef1d38e94cf3b75f8fb0->doDisplay(Array, Array)
#2 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\etc\templating\BaseTemplate.php(26): Twig_Template->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#3 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php(355): Craft\BaseTemplate->displayWithErrorHandling(Array, Array)
#4 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Template.php(366): Twig_Template->display(Array)
#5 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Environment.php(347): Twig_Template->render(Array)
#6 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\services\TemplatesService.php(248): Twig_Environment->render('503', Array)
#7 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\controllers\BaseController.php(74): Craft\TemplatesService->render('503', Array)
#8 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\controllers\TemplatesController.php(200): Craft\BaseController->renderTemplate('503', Array)
#9 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\framework\web\actions\CInlineAction.php(49): Craft\TemplatesController->actionRenderError()
#10 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#11 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php(286): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
#12 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\framework\web\CController.php(265): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
#13 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('renderError')
#14 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(368): CWebApplication->runController('templates/rende...')
#15 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\etc\errors\ErrorHandler.php(281): CErrorHandler->renderError()
#16 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(351): Craft\ErrorHandler->renderError()
#17 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(218): CErrorHandler->renderException()
#18 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\etc\errors\ErrorHandler.php(145): CErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Craft\HttpException))
#19 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\framework\base\CErrorHandler.php(131): Craft\ErrorHandler->handleException(Object(Craft\HttpException))
#20 C:\wamp64\www\west\craft\app\framework\base\CApplication.php(750): CErrorHandler->handle(Object(CExceptionEvent))
#21 [internal function]: CApplication->handleException(Object(Craft\HttpException))
#22 {main}
```

Here's the code from where the exception is thrown-

```
<title>        
    echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, $this->getAttribute((isset($context["global"]) ? $context["global"] : $this->getContext($context, "global")), "siteName", array()), "html", null, true);
    </title>
```

Template 503 -

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">

    <title>{{ global.siteName }}</title>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%; margin: 0;">

    <h1 style="text-align:center; margin: 100px 0 100px;">{{ global.siteName }}</h1>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Does this have anything to do with database connection? Eve if I delete the database, it's showing the same error.

Answer (score 5):

`siteName` is automatically global... you don't need to include the `global.` prefix.

```html
<title>{{ siteName }}</title>
```